# How can i change the name of a component inside joomla 3.2.3

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I'm trying to change the name of a component inside the admin menu, using Joomla 3.2.3

I can't seem to find it, already looked inside the database and the com_tijobs.xml file

Anyone has an idea how to change it?

Comment: I just found one link to the name inside the en-GB.com_tijobs.sys.ini but i'm still trying to find where it has to be changed for the page title - inside the joomla admin area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under administrator/language/en-GB/ you should have the files en-gb.com_tijobs.sys.ini and en-gb.com_tijobs.ini. In these two files, change the strings that give the name to your component.
Examples of the strings that name your component:

```
COM_TIJOBS="Your Component Name"
COM_TIJOBS_COMPONENT_LABEL="Your Component Name"
COM_TIJOBS_TITLE_TIJOBS="Your Component Name"
```

You can also find the references in your database in the #__menu table.

Answer (score 1):

The path to the files has been changed in 3.7. You will find the **"en-gb.com_mycomponent.sys.ini" and "en-gb.com_mycomponent.ini"** now under **administrator/components/com_mycomponent/language/.**
There you can change the strings which are used by the component and for example, easily change the name shown in the menu of joomla.

```
COM_MYCOMPONENT="Your Component Name"
COM_MYCOMPONENT_COMPONENT_LABEL="Your Component Name"
COM_MYCOMPONENT_TITLE="Your Component Name"
etc.
```